# What am I doing wrong in this jersey Java class?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

Here is the class :-

```
 package com.bablo.rest;

 import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
 import javax.ws.rs.Path;

 @Path("/")
 public class Library {
   @Produces("text/plain") 
   @Path("/books/{name}")
   public String getBook(@PathParam("name") String name){
     System.out.println(name);
      return "My Name is Anthony Goncalves";
  }
}
```

Its giving this as error

A sub-resource locator, public java.lang.String com.bablo.rest.Library.geBook(java.lang.String), can not have an entity parameter. Try to move the parameter to the corresponding resource method.

and

Missing dependency for method public java.lang.String com.bablo.rest.Library.getBook(java.lang.String) at parameter at index 0

I am invoking this webservice through the Browser like this

```
     http://localhost:8080/JAXRS-HelloWorld/rest/books/bablo
```

Also I am doing curl:

```
     curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/JAXRS-HelloWorld/rest/books/bablo
```

Comment: would you not use `import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;` ?

Comment: Mistake real silly mistake. Yes I would and should use that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you meant to use

```
javax.ws.rs.PathParam
```

rather than

```
javax.websocket.server.PathParam
```

Comment: Thanks on second track, please tell me even after correcting the above error I am not getting the String "My Name is Anthony Goncalves" as a result. I have annotated the getBook method with @Produces("text/plain")

Comment: @bablo Please update your question and show us how you invoke your webservice. What response do you get?

Comment: @bablo I'd like to see the result as well.

Comment: I am not getting any result. Its blank on the browser as well as on the commandline

Comment: @bablo I don't see why that would happen. Do you have any logs? Enable them at DEBUG/TRACE level and see what they say.

Answer (score 13):

You need to add tag either `@POST` or `@GET` above your method.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message but the reason was different in my case.
You could have been using:

```
@Post (oracle.jdbc.proxy.annotation)
```

but instead we should be using:

```
@POST (javax.ws.rs.POST)
```